# How to call two action in one form submission by one button click?

Tags: php, mysql

I Have a form in PHP. when I am clicking the submit button I want to take two actions at the same time. how do I do that?

```
<script>
     function myfunction(){

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'merchants.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('form was submitted');
            }
          });
      }


    </script>

<div class="stdFormHeader"> New Merchant Registration</div>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <label class="stdFormLabel">Merchant name : </label><input class="stdFormInput" type="text" name="merchantName" required><br>
<!--    <label class="stdFormLabel">Business Type : </label><select class="stdFormSelect" name="shopMarket" required>-->
<!--        <option value="shop">Shop</option>-->
<!--        <option value="market">Market Place</option>-->
<!--    </select><br>-->
    <label class="stdFormLabel">Contact Person : </label><input class="stdFormInput" type="text" name="contactPerson" required><br>
    <label class="stdFormLabel">Contact Number : </label><input class="stdFormInput" type="text" name="contactNumber" required><br>
    <label class="stdFormLabel">Address : </label><textarea class="stdFormInputBox" name="address"></textarea><br>

    <input class="stdFormButton"  type="submit" name="submit" onclick="myfunction()" value="Apply">
</form>
```

Comment: What kind of actions? For example javascript can listen when submit button is pressed and take actions. 
Anycase, please take a tour of the help centre to see how to ask a good question. We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: What actions? Can these both be done server side? If so, add more code to the form target handler.

Comment: Above is my code. I am currently submiitting my form through ajax. i want to send these data to another file as well. how do i take two actions with the same form and same button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a submit again:

```
 function myfunction(){

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'merchants.php',
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function () {
      alert('form was submitted');
    }
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'OtherFunction.php',
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function () {
      alert('form was submitted again');
    }
  });
}
```